# How to Draw Simple Line chart in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios6, linechart

I am a newbie to  the graph functionality in an iPhone application.

I am having array of numbers for which I want to make the simple static line graph without using the `coreplot` library since I have already tried this which seemed to me quite complicated.

Can anyone please fix out my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw Line chart using `CoreAnimation`.
Alternatively you can use `core plot` also : http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Answer (score 0):

hi You can Draw your simple line chart without using core plot just refer following link.

http://code4app.net/ios/Line-Chart/4fc844616803faf26a000002

here you can get demo for simple line graph.

I hope this will help full to you.

Comment: thanx for your kind help :) let me try this  one and then according to that i"ll response you soon.